# apt remove glob installing extra packages

Tags: ubuntu, apt, delete

when i just tried to uninstall all things poppler with
`apt remove *poppler* --autoremove`
apt tried to install 34 new packages. 
Why would this happen?

apt output:

```
# apt remove *poppler*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zathura-pdf-poppler' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'ruby-poppler' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'python2.7-poppler-dbg' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'poppler-utils' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'python3-poppler-qt5' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-cil' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-dev' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'python2.7-poppler' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-qt5-dev' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-cpp0' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'monodoc-poppler-manual' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-qt5-1' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-cil-dev' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-glib-dev' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-glib-doc' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpopplerkit0' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'qtdeclarative5-poppler-qml-plugin' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-private-dev' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'python-poppler-dbg' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-poppler-0.18' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-cpp-dev' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpopplerkit-dev' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'python-poppler' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-cpp0v5' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler-glib8' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'libpoppler79' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'poppler-data' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'xpoppler-utils' for glob '*poppler*'
Note, selecting 'qtdeclarative5-poppler1.0' for glob '*poppler*'
Package 'libpoppler-cpp0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xpoppler-utils' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'python-poppler' instead of 'python2.7-poppler'
Note, selecting 'python-poppler-dbg' instead of 'python2.7-poppler-dbg'
Note, selecting 'qtdeclarative5-poppler1.0' instead of 'qtdeclarative5-poppler-q                                                                                                                                        ml-plugin'
Package 'libpoppler-cil' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libpoppler-cil-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libpopplerkit-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libpopplerkit0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'monodoc-poppler-manual' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-poppler' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-poppler-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python3-poppler-qt5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'qtdeclarative5-poppler1.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ruby-poppler' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'zathura-pdf-poppler' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libpoppler-cpp-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libpoppler-cpp0v5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libpoppler-glib-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libpoppler-qt5-dev' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  catdoc cups-ipp-utils fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito
  fonts-droid-fallback fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-sil-gentium-basic gimp-data
  hplip-data inkscape-trunk-data libabw-0.1-1 libamd2 libapache-pom-java
  libbabl-0.1-0 libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-locale1.67.0
  libboost-thread1.67.0 libbsh-java libcamd2 libccolamd2 libcholmod3
  libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolamd2
  libcommons-logging-java libcommons-parent-java libcupscgi1 libde265-0
  libe-book-0.1-1 libemf1 libeot0 libepub0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1
  libexiv2-14 libfontembed1 libfreehand-0.1-1 libgegl-0.4-0 libgegl-common
  libgexiv2-2 libgimp2.0 libgs9-common libheif1 libhpmud0 libijs-0.35
  libjbig2dec0 libmetis5 libmhash2 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3
  libmypaint-1.3-0 libmypaint-common libmythes-1.2-0 libneon27-gnutls
  libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.13-0 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libplot2c2
  libpstoedit0c2a libqpdf21 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 libraw16 librdf0
  libreoffice-java-common libsane-hpaio libsuitesparseconfig5 libtumbler-1-0
  libumfpack5 libwps-0.4-4 libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libyajl2 lp-solve
  python-scour python3-olefile python3-pexpect python3-pil python3-ptyprocess
  python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-scour
  qpdf scour tumbler-common
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  colord colord-data foomatic-filters libbsd0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcolorhug2
  libexpat1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libjbig0:i386
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 liblzma5:i386
  libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libpaps0 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386
  libpoppler79:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libuuid1:i386
  libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb1:i386
  libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 paps poppler-utils:i386
  zlib1g:i386
Suggested packages:
  colord-sensor-argyll
Recommended packages:
  ghostscript poppler-data:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluez-cups cups cups-core-drivers cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers
  cups-x2go fig2dev ghostscript ghostscript-x gimp gir1.2-poppler-0.18 hplip
  inkscape-trunk libgs9 libkf5filemetadata-bin libpoppler-dev
  libpoppler-glib-dev libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler-private-dev libpoppler-qt5-1
  libpoppler79 libreoffice libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
  libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-librelogo libreoffice-math libreoffice-nlpsolver
  libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-report-builder
  libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-script-provider-bsh
  libreoffice-script-provider-js libreoffice-script-provider-python
  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql libreoffice-wiki-publisher libreoffice-writer
  poppler-data poppler-utils printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-pnm2ppa
  printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr
  printer-driver-sag-gdi printer-driver-splix pstoedit python3-uno tumbler
  xubuntu-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  colord colord-data foomatic-filters libbsd0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcolorhug2
  libexpat1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libjbig0:i386
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 liblzma5:i386
  libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libpaps0 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386
  libpoppler79:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libuuid1:i386
  libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb1:i386
  libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 paps poppler-utils:i386
  zlib1g:i386
0 upgraded, 34 newly installed, 55 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,361 kB of archives.
After this operation, 312 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of packages that depend on `libpoppler` or `poppler-utils` (directly or indirectly) in a default Ubuntu desktop installation.

Removing `popple-utils` means removing `cups-filter` which depends on it.

`printer-driver-foo2zjs` depends on `cups-filters | foomatic-filters` so it's possible to keep it as long as you install `foomatic-filters` which doesn't depend on `poppler-utils`.

`poppler-utils` *recommands* `colord` and you probably have apt configured to install *recommands* automatically (as it is by default). It also recommands `poppler-utils`. You've asked to remove the `poppler-utils` package, but the i386 version of it could still be installed instead.

In the end, `apt` tries to honour your request while minimising the damage (the number of other packages to remove), but in that case it results in a suboptimal choice as you end up with the same packages installed but in a foreign architecture.

There are many other possible alternative ways to resolve those dependency issues.

I personally always use `aptitude` for package management because it lets me choose how I want to resolve dependency conflicts.

In `aptitude`, I set the default view to *flat* (in options -> preferences, also tick the "advance to next entry" option), then you can more easily filter packages. For instance, by pressing <kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase `L`) to *limit* the view, and entering `~i poppler`, you get the list of installed packages whose name contains `poppler`.

Then, you can uninstall (<kbd>-</kbd>) or purge (<kbd>_</kbd>) each package, and as you do so, you'll notice `aptitude` flags a conflict (and some packages may turn red). You can then examine the conflict (<kbd>e</kbd>) and choose between a number of possible resolutions. You can also influence the resolution by approving or rejecting individual choice (like *remove that package*, *install that package*...).

Also note that the `*poppler*` in your `apt remove *poppler* --autoremove` should have been quoted. `*poppler*` is a shell glob. If there had been a `popplering` file for instance in the current directory, it would have been expanded by the shell, so you would have ended up running `apt remove popplering --autoremove`.

Some shells like csh, tcsh, fish, zsh (or `bash -O failglob`) would have let you realise your mistake in your case by reporting a `No match` error.